# getting error on sending mail

Tags: php, mailing

I know this question comes across a lot, but I just can't figure out how to do this using the, already answered posts.when iam sending an mail a popup box is appearing on the page like this.

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  250912  {main}( )   ...\contact.php:0
2   0.0010  251736  mail ( )    ...\contact.php:15
```

My code looks like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$to = "email@example.com";
$email = $_POST['contact-email'];
$subject = $_POST['contact-subject'];
$message = "Name: ".$_POST["contact-name"].""; 
$message .= "Number: ".$_POST["contact-number"].""; 
$message .= "Message: ".$_POST["contact-message"].""; 
$headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";

}
?>
 <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="">
        <h4>Drop us a line</h4>
        <div class="col-md-6"> <span>Enter Your Name* </span>
          <input name="contact-name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> <span>Enter Your Email*</span>
          <input name="contact-email" placeholder="E-Mail" type="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> <span>Enter Your number</span>
          <input name="contact-number" placeholder="Number" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> <span>Enter Your Subject</span>
          <input name="contact-subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12"> <span>Enter Your Message</span>
          <textarea name="contact-message" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <input class="form-send" value="Send Message" type="submit" name="submit">
        </div>
      </form>
```

iam testing it on localhost..i want to overcome from that,i dont whether it will be displaying when it will be on live..

Comment: so turn off your debugging

Comment: sorry iam new to php can you tell from where to debug

Comment: It's not an error. It's just the debug information, you can ignore it safely. As long as your system as the `sendmail` binary, there won't be a problem.

Comment: Loaded php.ini: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini but iam not seeing php.ini file in this path

Comment: i had turned off then also its showing